# SQLite - how to get average value?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column in my table that has values of type FLOAT. How can I get the average value of all items in this column?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
select avg( columnname) from table;
```

This  will average all rows. To average a subset, use a `where` clause. To average for each group (of something) use a `group by` clause.

Comment: Can you give an example with a `where` clause inside the `avg()`? When I try it in SQLite, I get a syntax error. Or does the `where` clause go outside the `avg()`? In that case, it would seem ambiguous... filtering the SELECT instead of the AVG().

Comment: @LarsH: e.x., `SELECT AVG(colname) FROM table WHERE otherCol = 'foo';` If it helps, think of the `WHERE` clause as being executed first, then the aggregate function `AVG()` operates on whatever rows remain.

Answer (score 9):

```
select avg(col1) from table;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select avg(column) from table;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT AVG(column) FROM ...
```