# How do you store a computation by an SQLite operation?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to take the average of a column of data in my SQLite table. The column is called number. So I wrote the following code:

```
private findMaxNumber(){
        db.execSQL("select avg(number) from table");        
}
```

But I don't understand what this yields. What kind of format is the number being stored in?

I have declared

```
private int average
```

and I want to set average equal to the value of that computed in the database.

How do I do this?

I tried

```
private findMaxNumber(){
        average = db.execSQL("select avg(number) from table"); 

}
```

But this didn't work. It said "integer" and "void" are incompatible. I assume this means my SQLite code didn't yield any result. But then they said here [SQLite - how to get average value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797053/sqlite-how-to-get-average-value) that this was the appropriate SQLite code to find the average, so I'm confused what's going on.

UPDATE:

```
protected void createDatabase(){
            db= openOrCreateDatabase("NuPersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR,address VARCHAR, date TEXT,number INTEGER);");
        }
```

Comment: Function call must have return value, either void or float

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Android SQLite so it will not give you direct result from executing query, it will return `Cursor` from which you need to take value, check below.

```
  private int findMaxNumber()
  {
      int average = 0;
      String selectQuery = "select avg(number) from table";

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      if(cursor.moveToFirst())
      {
          average = cursor.getInt(0);
      }

      return average;
  }
```

Comment: I added an update. The code in the update is how I created my database. is this incompatible with .getWritableDatabase()? It's showing up red in my code and I already added the     import  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
but that's not doing anything.

Comment: It's not enough to import, also you need to extend SQLiteOpenHelper by your db class, check this link for better understand : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

`execSQL()` does not return data.
To get actual values from the database, you must user `rawQuery()` instead, which returns a `Cursor` object.

Reading a single value from a cursor requires additional `moveToFirst()` and `getXxx()` calls. This happens so often that there is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) for it:

```
average = (int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select avg(number) from table", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

That´s because a SQL operation always retrieves a ResultSet unless specified upon a stored procedure.

Here try this:

```
       import java.sql.Connection;
       import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
       import java.sql.ResultSet;
       import java.sql.SQLException;
       import java.sql.Statement;

       .....

        // Your connection parameter
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        conn = ds.getConnection(con);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();                
        String sql = "Select avg(number) from table";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.next()){
          int average = rs.getInt(0);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to perform the operation like below. The average value of any column would be float value. So we declared float value and using the cursor object get the selected value. If you want to open Data Base use the below method.

```
private float findMaxNumber(){
        String sql = "select avg(number) from table";
        float average = 0;
        Cursor cursor;
        try {
            openDataBase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                average = cursor.getFloat(0);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return average;

    }

    public static synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        // String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        if (db == null) {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|  SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

        } else if (!db.isOpen()) {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|  SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

        }
        return db;
    }
```